# Unable to test @Retryable in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-batch

I have gone through some posts but I am finding it hard to write a test case for my class. Below is the configuration for my `ItemReader`

```
@Component
@EnableRetry
public class MyReader implements ItemReader<User> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyReader.class);
    private final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;


    public MyReader(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClientBuilder = webClientBuilder;
    }


    @Override
    @Retryable(value = WebClientRequestException.class, maxAttempts = 4, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))

    public User read() {

        LOGGER.info("Sending GET request to get user data");
        return webClientBuilder.build().get().uri("http://localhost:8000/").retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::is5xxServerError,
                error -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Server is not responding")))
            .bodyToMono(User.class).block();

    }
}
```

I have written the test case like below

```
@SpringBootTest
class SampleTest {
    @Autowired
    Myreader myReader;

    @Mock
    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
    
     @Mock
    private WebClient webClient;

    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec requestHeadersUriSpec;

    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpec;

    @Mock
    private WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec;

@Test
    void testRetry() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myReader,"webClientBuilder",webClientBuilder);
        Throwable t= new RuntimeException();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders= new HttpHeaders();
        User expectedUser =  User.builder().build();
        Mono<User> monoUser = Mono.just(expectedUser);
        // Mock WebClient behavior to simulate a server error
        when(webClientBuilder.build()).thenReturn(webClient);
        when(webClient.get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriSpec);
        when(requestHeadersUriSpec.uri("http://localhost:8000/")).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
        when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
        when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve())
            .thenThrow(new WebClientRequestException(t, null, null, httpHeaders))
            .thenThrow(new WebClientRequestException(t, null, null, httpHeaders))
            .thenThrow(new WebClientRequestException(t, null, null, httpHeaders))
            .thenReturn(responseSpec);
        when(responseSpec.onStatus(any(), any())).thenReturn(responseSpec);
        when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(User.class)).thenReturn(monoUser);


        myReader.read();

        // Call the read() method and assert that a WebClientRequestException is thrown
       WebClientRequestException exception = assertThrows(WebClientRequestException.class, itemReader::read);

        // Verify the interactions
        verify(webClientBuilder, times(4)).build().get();
    }
    
    
}
```

I am getting error like below

> Expected
> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException

Also in the stack trace I observed a log like below

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException:
> Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8000
> at
> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136)
> ~[spring-webflux-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]

Which means the `webClient` is actually trying to connect the ip address I have provided when I already mocked the behaviour of `webClient`. Where am I going wrong?

**Edit**

I did the modification . I changed  the annotation from `@Mock` to

```
@MockBean
private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
```

and rest of the code part is same . But now I am getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder.build()"
```

below is complete stack trace. Not sure why `ItemWriter` is involved here

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'myJob' defined in class path resource [com/example/MyConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'myJob' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'myStep' defined in class path resource [com/example//MyConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'myStep' parameter 3: Error creating bean with name 'myItemWriter' defined in file [C:\Users\user1\intellijProjects\my-template\my-project\build\classes\java\main\com\gov\sg\br2s\batch\lcr\chunk\myItemWriter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'webConfigProperties' defined in class path resource [com/example/MyConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [sg.gov.br2s.portal.lib.web.http.DefaultWebClient]: Factory method 'webConfigProperties' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder.build()"
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:793)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:242)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at app//org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:59)
    at app//org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:47)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1386)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:543)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:183)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myJob' defined in class path resource [com/example/MyConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'myJob' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'myStep' defined in class path resource [com/example/MyConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'myStep' parameter 3: Error creating bean with name 'myItemWriter' defined in file [C:\Users\user1\intellijProjects\my-template\my-project\build\classes\java\main\com\gov\sg\br2s\batch\lcr\chunk\myItemWriter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'webConfigProperties' defined in class path resource [com/example/MyConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [sg.gov.br2s.portal.lib.web.http.DefaultWebClient]: Factory method 'webConfigProperties' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder.build()"
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:793)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:543)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:880)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:784)
    ... 111 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myStep' defined in class path resource [com/example/MyConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'myStep' parameter 3: Error creating bean with name 'myItemWriter' defined in file [C:\Users\user1\intellijProjects\my-template\my-project\build\classes\java\main\com\gov\sg\br2s\batch\lcr\chunk\myItemWriter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'webConfigProperties' defined in class path resource [com/example/MyConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [sg.gov.br2s.portal.lib.web.http.DefaultWebClient]: Factory method 'webConfigProperties' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder.build()"
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:793)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:543)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:880)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:784)
    ... 125 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myItemWriter' defined in file [C:\Users\user1\intellijProjects\my-template\my-project\build\classes\java\main\com\gov\sg\br2s\batch\lcr\chunk\myItemWriter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'webConfigProperties' defined in class path resource [com/example/MyConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [sg.gov.br2s.portal.lib.web.http.DefaultWebClient]: Factory method 'webConfigProperties' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder.build()"
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:793)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:242)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:880)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:784)
    ... 139 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webConfigProperties' defined in class path resource [com/example/MyConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [sg.gov.br2s.portal.lib.web.http.DefaultWebClient]: Factory method 'webConfigProperties' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder.build()"
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:652)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:880)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:784)
    ... 153 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [sg.gov.br2s.portal.lib.web.http.DefaultWebClient]: Factory method 'webConfigProperties' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder.build()"
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    ... 167 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder.build()"
    at sg.gov.br2s.portal.lib.web.http.AbstractWebClient.<init>(AbstractWebClient.java:26)
    at sg.gov.br2s.portal.lib.web.http.DefaultWebClient.<init>(DefaultWebClient.java:23)
    at com.gov.sg.br2s.batch.lcr.configuration.MyConfiguration.webConfigProperties(MyConfiguration.java:81)
    at com.gov.sg.br2s.batch.lcr.configuration.MyConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$webConfigProperties$0(<generated>)
    at com.gov.sg.br2s.batch.lcr.configuration.MyConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:257)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com.gov.sg.br2s.batch.lcr.configuration.MyConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.webConfigProperties(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
    ... 168 more
```

Comment: For one thing, you're not injecting your mocks so your MyReader object has the real webclient.

Comment: Your issue is related to the test setup of the `WebClient` and not really the item reader. I would first remove the Spring Batch bits from the test and make sure to have a test correctly set up with a web client. BTW, why is the reader's constructor accepting a WebClient.Builder and not a WebClient?

Answer (score 0):

In your test, you've marked it as a `SpringBootTest`, which means the Spring context is spinning up and that autowiring of the `Myreader` is pulling in the bean from the context, which has a real `WebClient.Builder`.

This will probably work with one simple but not-so-obvious modification.

Change

```
@Mock
private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
```

To

```
@MockBean
private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
```

This will still create the mock you expect but will also register this as the WebClient.Builder bean in the Spring context, so the injected instance will be your mock.

Comment: Did the modifications as you suggested now I am getting NullPointerException

Comment: @kondasurekha it looks like you're calling the build in a configuration classs?  MyConfiguration.java:81.  Try running your test through a debugger, you should be able to pin this down fairly quickly.